# How to use in Vuejs3/setup method in mixins?

Tags: vuejs3

In vuejs3 app I try to use in setup method in mixins, like I used in vuejs2
My src/appMixin.js have:

```js
import moment from 'moment-timezone'
import { settingsAwesomeFontLabels } from './app.settings.js'
    
export default {
  
  methods: {
  
    getClone: function (obj) {
      let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
      return copy
    },

  }
}
```

and in my vue file :

```js
import appMixin from '@/appMixin'
import app from './../../App.vue' // eslint-disable-line
import axios from 'axios' // eslint-disable-line

// ...

  setup () {
    function loadCategories() {
      isPageLoaded = false
      let credentials = getClone(credentialsConfig)
      credentials.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + currentLoggedUserToken.value

          // ...
```

With getClone method I want to get credentialsConfig from settings.js file
and modify headers with token of current login.
But in console where I run command

```sh
$ yarn run serve
```

I see error :

```
/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/VApps/yt3/src/admin/categories/list.vue
  234:27  error  'getClone' is not defined  no-undef
```

and error in the broswer's console:

```
list.vue?c790:233 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getClone is not defined
```

I suppose because of error in console

Which is correct way to export/import getClone into setup method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could refactor this to use a `composition function` instead of a mixin. For example, your `getClone` function would be in a file `useGetClone.js`:

```js
export default function (obj) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Then in any component you want to use it:

```js
import getClone from `@/composables/useGetClone`;

export default {
    setup() {
        // …

        const getClone = useGetClone(credentials);

        // …

        return {};
    },
};
```

Comment: My mixin has a lot of methods. I suppose that I can put all methods in 1 js file with export default function declarations. Have I to write import methodName any time when I need to use methodName ? mixin can not be used with vuejs3 ?

Comment: If everything is logically related to `getClone` then there's nothing stopping you from exporting an object that contains all of the related functions, i.e. `export default { funcOne() {}, funcTwo() {} };`

Comment: @mstdmstd Matt is right, please read the last line [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html#precautions)